# WPF Binding Collection: Почему не обновляются данные?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, xaml

Почему не обновляются данные в первой таблице (MyItems), когда я редактирую (добавляю, удаляю, изменяю) вторую таблицу (MySubItems)?

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="CollectionBindingsExample.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CollectionBindingsExample"
Title="SubCollectionSample" Height="350" Width="525" FontSize="22" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.Resources>
        <l:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="mainWindowViewModel" />
        <l:CollectionToString x:Key="collectionToString" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource mainWindowViewModel}" />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Path=Collection}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Header="MyItems">
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Name}"
                    />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Collection" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding SubCollection, Converter={StaticResource collectionToString}}"
                    />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Header="MySubItems">
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubCollection}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Name}"
                    />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Globalization;

namespace CollectionBindingsExample
{
    class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            Collection = new Collection();
            Collection.Add(new MyItem());
            Collection.Add(new MyItem());
            Collection.Add(new MyItem());

            int i = 0;
            foreach (MyItem item1 in Collection)
            {
                item1.Name = "Item" + i;

                item1.SubCollection.Add(new MySubItem());
                item1.SubCollection.Add(new MySubItem());

                int j = 0;
                foreach (MySubItem item2 in item1.SubCollection)
                {
                    item2.Name = "SubItem" + i + "_" + j;
                    j++;
                } i++;
            }
        }
        public Collection Collection
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
    }
    [ValueConversion(typeof(SubCollection), typeof(String))]
    public class CollectionToString : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            SubCollection collection = (SubCollection)value;
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (MySubItem v in collection)
            {
                s = s.Append(v.Name).Append(", ");
            } return s.ToString();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Models.cs

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace CollectionBindingsExample
{
    class MyItem
    {
        public MyItem()
        {
            SubCollection = new SubCollection();
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public SubCollection SubCollection
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
    }
    class Collection : ObservableCollection<MyItem>
    {
    }
    class MySubItem
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
    class SubCollection : ObservableCollection<MySubItem>
    {
    }
}
```

По совету Ilya Pirogov'а я в Models.cs реализовал NotifyPropertyChanged. Все равно не работает.

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace CollectionBindingsExample
{
class MyItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyItem()
    {
        SubCollection = new SubCollection();
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }

    public SubCollection SubCollection { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string type)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(type));
        }
    }
}

class Collection : ObservableCollection<MyItem> { }

class MySubItem: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MySubItem() { }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    { 
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string type)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(type));
        }
    }

}

class SubCollection : ObservableCollection<MySubItem>
{
    public SubCollection() { }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPD.** Был не прав.

Возможно нужно реализовать интерфейс [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) для классов `MySubItem` и `MyItem` соответственно.

**UPD 2.**

Вы не реализовали самого главного - оповещение об изменении свойства `SubCollection` (ведь именно на это свойство вы забиндили вторую колонку) при любых изменений внутри коллекции. Т.е. должно быть примерно следующее:

```
class MyItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyItem()
    {
        SubCollection = new SubCollection();
        // подписываемся на изменения самой коллекции
        SubCollection.CollectionChanged += SubCollectionChanged;
    }

    void SubCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        INotifyPropertyChanged item;

        NotifyPropertyChanged("SubCollection");

        // если объекты всего-лишь поменялись местами, то пропускаем
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move)
        {
            return;
        }

        // отписываемся от всех удаленных объектов из коллекции
        if (e.OldItems != null && e.OldItems.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var oldItem in e.OldItems)
            {
                item = oldItem as INotifyPropertyChanged;
                if (item != null)
                {
                    item.PropertyChanged -= ItemPropertyChanged;
                }
            }
        }

        // и подписываемся на оповещение об изменении всех новых объект коллекции
        if (e.NewItems != null && e.NewItems.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var newItem in e.NewItems)
            {
                item = newItem as INotifyPropertyChanged;
                if (item != null)
                {
                    item.PropertyChanged += ItemPropertyChanged;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void ItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SubCollection");
    }

    // далее остальная реализация класса MyItem
    // ...
}
```